# bootstrap a hfref dropdown is not clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i add a dropdown in my website header but when i try to add a link "[www.domain.com/test](http://www.domain.com/test)", this dropdown submenus is not clickable. Now when I click on the link, I should be taken to the page domain.com ,but the links do not work.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified blocks" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn">
    <a class="btndrp" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="img-nav"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></span><p class="img-text">View Cart</p><span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="secondli"><a href="www.domain.com/test"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> View Cart</a></li>
            <li class="secondli"><a href="www.domain.com/test"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i> Checkout Now</a></li>
        </ul>                      
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Add http:// to your links

Comment: even with http is the same situation

Comment: i read a lot of articles, the people talk about this data-toggle attribute, maybe this will be problem ...

Comment: I don't see nested a tags. You're code looks valid, can you produce this where we can test it?

Comment: i think i found the problem, i remove this data-toggle="buttons" and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                if ($(this).find(".secondli"))
                {
                    $('a').on("click", function() {
                        window.location.href="http://www.domain.com/test";
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
```